# A Question on Lebesgue Decomposition

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

How can I show that the Lebesgue measure has no Lebesgue decomposition with respect to the counting measure? I know how to show that reverse is true, but just can't figure out how to show this direction.

Answer (score 2):

The Lebesgue measure has a Lebesgue decomposition with respect to the counting measure. It is just $m = m + 0$, the zero measure is singular with respect to all measures, and $m \ll |\cdot|$, since if the counting measure is zero, the set must be empty.

Suppose $|\cdot| = \nu_0+\nu_1$, where $\nu_0 \ll m$, and $\nu_1 \bot m$.

If $\nu_1 \bot m$, then $\nu_1$ must be supported on a set of $m$ measure zero. Let $N$ be this set. Now choose $x \notin N$. Then $|\{x\}| = 1$, $m \{x\} = 0$ (and hence $\nu_0 \{x\} = 0$) and $\nu_1 \{x\} = 0$ (since $x \notin N$), which is a contradiction. Hence the counting measure does not have a Lebesgue decomposition with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, thanks. But what happens if we restrict the space to just be the interval [0,1]? Does this decomposition still work?

Comment: Of course. Any subset of $[0,1]$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, you you can apply the measures and decompositions to the 'restriction'.

Comment: The counting measure has no Lebesgue decomposition:

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1177388/88132

Comment: What is your point?