# Show that the counting measure has no Lebesgue decomposition.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$, and $\lambda$ the counting measure on $(0,1)$. I am trying to prove that there is **no** decomposition
$$\lambda=\lambda_a+\lambda_s$$
where $\lambda_a$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $m$, and $\lambda_s$ is singular with respect to $m$.

I am trying to show that the decomposition would give a contradiction, but I am stuck. Any idea?

**My attempt:** We get $\lambda(E)=\lambda_s(E)$ for all countable sets $E$, so (maybe) this implies that $\lambda=\lambda_s$ and hence $\lambda\perp m$, which is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my attempt. For each $x \in (0,1)$, we have $1 = \lambda (x) = \lambda_a (x) + \lambda_s(x) = 0 + \lambda_s(x)$. So, $\lambda_s(x) = 1 \ \forall x \in (0, 1)$. Since $\lambda_s$ and $m $ are mutually singular, there exist $A \sqcup B = (0,1)$ s.t. $m(A)= \lambda_s(B) = 0$. Now, if $B$ is nonempty, take $x \in B$, and note that $\lambda_s(B) \geq \lambda_s(x) =1 $, a contradiction. So $B = \emptyset.$ And since $A, B$ disjoint, we have $A= (0,1)$, leading to $0 = m(A)=m((0,1))=1$. A contradiction. So no lebesgue decomposition exists.

Comment: But why we have $A\cup B =(0,1)$? In Rudin's book, we only need $A\cap B=\emptyset$, so there is no need for $A\cup B=(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there exist such a decomposition.

As $\lambda_a$ is absolutely continuous, $\lambda_a(\{x\}) = 0 \forall x$. Hence $\lambda_s(\{x\}) = 1 \forall x$

But as $\lambda_s$ is singular,  there exist a set $S\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\forall B\in \mathcal{B}(S), \lambda_s(B) = 0$.

But this set contain a $x$, so $\{ x \} \in \mathcal{B}(S)$. Then $\lambda_s(\{x\}) = 0 $:  contradiction

Comment: $\lambda_a$ being absolutely continuous means that if $\lambda(S)=0$ then $\lambda_a(S)=0$.  Why can you assume that $\lambda_a(\{x\})=0$?

Comment: @Squirtle I upvoted your comment, but you are actually wrong.  $\lambda_{a}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure $m$.  So since $m( \{ x \}) = 0$, then $\lambda_{a}( \{ x \} ) = 0$.  It's important to specify which measure you are absolutely continuous with respect to.

Comment: Yeah.... I agree... i made a typo, my $\lambda$ above should be $m$.

Comment: @Squirtle : for all x, $m(\{x\}) = 0$, then, as $\lambda_a$ is absolutly continuous with respect to $m$,for all x, $\lambda_a(\{x\}) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the purely atomic and nonatomic decomposition of any measure then my answer will work wonderfully... otherwise, you may consider studying the great classic and very readable [Atomic and Nonatomic Measures](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-03/S0002-9939-1970-0279266-8/S0002-9939-1970-0279266-8.pdf) by Roy A. Johnson.

Proof:  Suppose such a decomposition exists.  As $\lambda$ is atomic (the singletons are its atoms), and $m$ is nonatomic such that $m \ll \lambda$ then $\lambda \perp m$ by Theorem 2.3 of the paper.  Hence $m\perp (\lambda_a + \lambda_s)$, but as 
$m\perp \lambda_s$ this implies $m\perp \lambda_a$ but we also assumed that $\lambda_a\ll m$.  Because $m\perp \lambda_a \ll m$ we conclude that $m=0$ (the zero measure), a contradiction.